# How to make all fields the same height in Contact Form 7?

Tags: css, wordpress, contacts, contact-form-7

I want to make Contact Forms on my 2 personal websites the same, and i copy the same contact form from [first site](http://deil.cz/thelab/#contact) and paste into [second site](http://deilbeatz.com/#contact), but contact form looks a little smashed. How to make fields height on both sites the same?

Comment: Your forms are literally identical on both pages. Please update your question so that it shows all relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also be sure to let us know what you have tried so far to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the [help article](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) regarding how to ask good questions.

Comment: For example, i just added this CSS:

`body .twenty-fifteen-pattern p {
  padding-bottom:10px;
}`

and add a spacing between fields. How to customize the same height like first site?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `display: flex` for the `form`. There are bunch of other properties to play around to achieve what you want. like `justify-content: center` and `flex-wrap: wrap` for parent, `flex: 1` for children.

With its wide browser support, I'd suggest you to take a look at this visualised article about CSS Flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/